How to put MAUI Menu bar in bottom position?
I need to show a menu bar ("windows style), as described https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/menu-bar?view=net-maui-8.0
but I would like to put it on the bottom, something like old W.M. programs; Is there a way to do that? The app will run on android and maybe on ios.

From the doc, Display a menu bar in a .NET MAUI desktop app

A .NET Multi-platform App UI (.NET MAUI) menu bar is a container that
presents a set of menus in a horizontal row, at the top of an app on
Mac Catalyst and Windows.

The menu bar is only for Mac Catalyst and Windows. For Android, you may try using toolbar items.
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Add item"
             IconImageSource="add.png" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

For more info, you may refer to Display toolbar items.
